# Spring Mvc Hibernate Srored procedure

Tags: spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am new to spring mvc and hibernate

I want to get data to List  calling from Stored procedure in spring mvc . that store procedure include query which run on few tables. Is it need to create entity classes according to tables used in stored procedure ?
if no need of that kind of thing how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Native Queries in hibernate.

Just search how to use native queries in hibernate.